# python multiple project practice

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

So I have multiple projects like

```
DevelFolder/
   ├──MyuniversalModule/
      ├── .git
      ├── __init__.py
      └── mymodule.py
   ├──project01/
      └── myproject01.py
   └──project02/
      └── myproject02.py
```

Now, In my 2 projects I would like to import "MyuniversalModule" which I have been developing separately and it is still work in progress and i will be changing it for needs of my projects. After finishing those projects, I will add this module but at this moment I would like to develop and test it separately, as it may be used in multiple places.

I was searching for solutions, like importing from parent directory

```
from ... import module
```

or

```
import imp
foo = imp.load_source('module.name', '/path/to/file.py')
foo.MyClass()
```

or

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', '..'))
```

But what is the best practise of working in such situation ?

Answer (score 2):

Relative imports are usually only used for submodules which are unique to your project. If you have a module which will be shared by multiple projects, a common practice is to package it separately as a pip package, and then in each new project use

```
pip install local/path/to/my/other/package
```

to install it as a requirement. You can also use `pip install git+ssh` to install from a private git server.

Comment: but When I am still developing "MyuniversalModule", you suggest I would have to package and install each time i change something within that module in order to test it in my projects. I would like to keep them interactive until it is ready to use. Otherwise I could also pull it from github, right ?

Comment: yes you would run `pip install --upgrade` each time you change something (you don't actually have to execute anything to package, a pip package is just a particular directory tree structure / config file required by pip)

Answer (score 1):

Consider expecting the paths to other modules as environment variables.

```py
def add_to_syspath(name):
    module_path = os.environ[name] if name in os.environ else None

    if module_path is None:
        raise RuntimeError(f'{name} not found in the environment variables.')
    elif not os.path.exists(module_path):
        raise RuntimeError(f'{name} module not found: {module_path}')

    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(module_path))
```

Then either in your system-wide or project-specific environment variables you can specify where particular projects reside on your system.

Win: `setx MY_UNIVERSAL_MODULE_PATH "C:\lib\my_universal_module"`

Linux: `export MY_UNIVERSAL_MODULE_PATH ="~/lib/my_universal_module"`

Or do it through the appropriate GUI.

This way including a module will be as simple as:

```py
# inside of myproject01.py
add_to_syspath('MY_UNIVERSAL_MODULE_PATH')
from mymodule import foo # check that your import worked
```